# .NET Informix error

Tags: sql, vb.net, informix

I keep getting an error when trying to connect to an Informix database.

I am using VS2008, .NET 4 framework, IBM Informix Connect 3.7 64bit

The code

```
Dim connectionstring As String =  "myconnectionstring"

    Dim conn As New IfxConnection

    conn.ConnectionString = connectionstring
    Try
        conn.Open()
        MsgBox("Made connection!")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

I know that the connection string works because this exact code works on my old 32-bit machine.

The error

```
Unable to load DLL IfxDotNetIntrinsic Module.dll the specific module could not be found
```

I've checked the Setnet 32 and it is correct, I have uninstalled and reinstalled the driver.  I just don't know what to do next — can you help?

Comment: You don't tell us about your current Platform (x86 or AnyCpu) and wheter your working pc has a 32bit or 64bit OS.

Comment: WOW! I thought I was the only one in the world connecting to Informix via .NET.  Sorry, I don't think I can help; I'm using 32-bit ODBC.  Good Luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FYI:** The .NET Provider shipped with Informix client SDK is compiled with .NET Framework 2.0 (not FW 4.0).

If you are trying to use .NET provider from 32-bit Informix Client SDK on Windows 64-bit system then you may need to manually copy the following DLL to a location where it has path set.

```
<Informix Client Install Dir>\bin\netf20\IfxDotNetIntrinsicModule.dll
```

Most likely path may have already set to `<Informix Client Install Dir>\bin`.
Then that may be an ideal location to copy it.